# Unable To Create Directory Permission Denied Error In Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react ios app for first time. So everything was working fine. But I just installed React Native Vector Icons and used `react-native link` command. From that I can't build my xcode project.

It gives bunch of error with a popup everytime I start xcode.

Popup says something about Unlocking React-Native-vector-icons. And when I tap on unlock it doesn't work.

And when I build, It gives me the following error

```
Check dependencies

error: Unable to create directory: /Users/buckydroid/Desktop/ReactProject/AyeMobile/ios/Build/Intermediates (Permission denied)
error: Unable to create directory: /Users/buckydroid/Desktop/ReactProject/AyeMobile/ios/Build/Products (Permission denied)

Write auxiliary files

/bin/mkdir -p /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build
    error: Unable to create directory: /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build (Permission denied)
    /bin/mkdir -p /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build
    error: Unable to create directory: /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build (Permission denied)
    /bin/mkdir -p /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64
    error: Unable to create directory: /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64 (Permission denied)
    /bin/mkdir -p /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build
    error: Unable to create directory: /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build (Permission denied)
    /bin/mkdir -p /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build
    error: Unable to create directory: /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build (Permission denied)
    /bin/mkdir -p /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build
    error: Unable to create directory: /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build (Permission denied)
    /bin/mkdir -p /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build
    error: Unable to create directory: /Users/user/Desktop/ReactProject/App/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build (Permission denied)
```

When I build it through terminal using `sudo react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X"` command, it works. But never opens on simulator.

Need Help :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, Weird but I just restarted my mac and it worked .-.